# Differential equation curve from fractional calculus

Tags: fractional-calculus

Is it possible to form  differential equation of curves basically defined in fractional calculus

$$F(x,q)=\frac{x^(1 - q)}{\Gamma[2 - q]} + 
  2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} unitstep(x - 2 k + 1)(-1)^k\frac{(x - 2k + 1)^(1 - q)}{
      \Gamma[2 - q]}  ? $$

e.g.,for the following

$$ F( x,-\frac12 )? $$

[image]